# mavROS, SITL ArduPlane: commands in GUIDED mode are rejected

Tags: python, ros, mavlink

A simple python script publishes commands to the mavros node which is connected to an arduplane SITL instance.
Succesfully publishing to change mode from AUTO to GUIDED (so no connection or other issues). After changing, the plane is loitering.

Publishing to the services *~cmd/command* or *~cmd/command_int* the commands are rejected (return code 3).

Publishing to the topic *~setpoint_raw/global* has no effect whatsoever.

The published command is a simple **16 MAV_CMD_NAV_WAYPOINT**

The question is: is there **any way** that I can use any of the topics/services of mavros in order to simply stream waypoints (pairs of global coordinates) for the UAV to follow (in GUIDED or in any other mode).

I think that clearing and continuously uploading a mission in AUTO is not exactly an option since it would delay significantly.

Please note that the solution is intendeed for a fixed wing (aka Plane).

**Versions:**

**ROS**: Kinetic

**ArduPilot**: 3.8.0beta5

The issue has also been raised in [mavros](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/issues/712) and [Ardupilot](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/issues/6279) hubs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do that using GCS and it failed too?
I also suggest to try [dronekit](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/copter/guided_mode.html) . It is in python and simple to implement and send commands for the vehicle.

Comment: In what way are you suggesting using the GCS for that? "Unfortunatelly" I have to use mavros since it's for a research project and it's a part of a bigger ROS architecture. Nevertheless, I've just seen on the dronekit website that: "_This topic is Copter specific. Plane apps typically use AUTO mode and dynamically modify missions as needed (Plane supports GUIDED mode but it is less full featured than on Copter)._" , so I will try that way also.